# Remove BOM Character from soap response : SOAP: looks like we got no XML document

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, byte-order-mark

Hi I am a beginning in creating webservices,

I'm trying to create a web service by using soap protocol and I keep getting the following error:looks like we got no XML document.

Here is below my web service  and output of response. As you will see i'm getting bom character (ï»¿ï»¿ï»¿) in begining of response.. i think that this the root cause of error getted that specify the xml is not valid.Please is there any way to remove those character  from my client. so i'm noticing that i've tried to override _doRequest method of SoapClient but no success. My wsdl file and sever script are all encoded in UTF-8 Without BOM.

Any help to solve this issue will be very appreciated.

regards.

client:

```
try{
    ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");// disabling WSDL cache
    libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);
    if(!extension_loaded("soap")){ dl("php_soap.dll");  }
    $client2 = new SoapClient("http://www.payafrik.com/PayAfrikAPI.wsdl",array("wsdl_cache"=>0,"trace"=>1,"exception"=>1));
    $slabrequest["email"]  = "tes@gmail.com";
    $slabrequest["description"] = "test";
    $slabrequest["montant"]    = 50000;
    $client2->slabAccount($slabrequest);
}catch(Exception $e){ 
    var_dump( $e ); 
    echo "<pre>"; echo "Request :<br/>", htmlentities($client2->__getLastRequest()), "<br/>"; 
    echo "Response :<br/>", htmlentities($client2->__getLastResponse()), "<br/>";echo "</pre>";
}
```

..
Output of Response :
**ï»¿ï»¿ï»¿**
repSUCCESSuser4MonsieurGNACADJALoic 1RUE 1382LITTORAL1229COTONOU22921332680229972461401987-03-26loic.gnacadja@gmail.com646260ea6e66c61704c695e617f9b74alogin1309625000011242015-07-12 23:50:30

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit old question, but had this same issue, so will leave my solution to this problem, in case someone get directed here by Google :)

Looks like not only BOM, but any extra data, like new lines, before XML data, will make **SoapClient** report this error. Very often we are just clients of some service, so we can not change the message we get, or server configuration.

## Solution that worked for me

By setting **SoapClient** trace to true, and calling [SoapClient::__getLastResponse](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastresponse.php) I found that part that is interesting me is starting with **<s:Envelope**
To get rid of extra, not needed data, had to extend **SoapClient**, to cut only required information, and let **SoapClient** do the rest, with valid result.

Ended up with something as simple like this:

```
class WSDLSoapClient extends SoapClient {
    public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0) {
        $response = parent::__doRequest( $request, $location, $action, $version );
        if (!$response) {
            return $response;
        }
        // Cut only part that is a SOAP result
        $matches = array();
        preg_match('/<s:Envelope.*<\/s:Envelope>/s', $response, $matches);
        return $matches[0];
    }
}
```

Hope it helps,
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
ob_start();
try(){
    //
}catch(){
   //
}finally(){
  ob_end_clean();
}
//Use finally block with ob_end_clean() function to clean BOM characters
```